# How to merge default values into nested params in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested, applicationcontroller

I am desperately trying to merge a set of default values into my nested params. Unfortunately, using `deep_merge` no longer works in Rails 5 since it no longer inherits from `Hash`.

So this does **not** work:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @company = current_account.companies.build(company_params)
    if @company.save
      flash[:success] = "Company created."
      redirect_to companies_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(
      :name,
      :email,
      :people_attributes => [
        :first_name,
        :last_name
      ]
    ).deep_merge(
      :creator_id => current_user.id,
      :people_attributes => [
        :creator_id => current_user.id
      ]
    )
  end

end
```

It gives me this error:

> undefined method `deep_merge' for ActionController::Parameters:0x007fa24c39cfb0

So how can it be done?

Answer (score 6):

Since there seems to be no similar implementation of `deep_merge` in Rails 5 `ActionController::Parameters` by looking at this [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h), then you can just simply do `.to_h` to convert it first into a [`ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) (which is a subclass of a `Hash`):

> **to_h()** Returns a safe ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess representation of the parameters with all unpermitted keys removed.

```
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(
    :name,
    :email,
    :people_attributes => [
      :first_name,
      :last_name
    ]
  ).to_h.deep_merge(
    :creator_id => current_user.id,
    :people_attributes => [
      :creator_id => current_user.id
    ]
  )
end
```